# Angular 2 code suggestions on IntelliJ

Tags: intellij-idea, autocomplete, typescript, angular

I saw that Angular2 RC was released earlier this month, and I was playing with the beta version for months, so I decided to delete the angular2 beta module with

```
npm uninstall angular2
```

then I used the package.json from the angular2 quickstart tutorial to install the RC release:

```
{
  "name": "angular2-quickstart",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "tsc && concurrently \"npm run tsc:w\" \"npm run lite\" ",
    "lite": "lite-server",
    "postinstall": "typings install",
    "tsc": "tsc",
    "tsc:w": "tsc -w",
    "typings": "typings"
  },
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/common":  "2.0.0-rc.1",
    "@angular/compiler":  "2.0.0-rc.1",
    "@angular/core":  "2.0.0-rc.1",
    "@angular/http":  "2.0.0-rc.1",
    "@angular/platform-browser":  "2.0.0-rc.1",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic":  "2.0.0-rc.1",
    "@angular/router":  "2.0.0-rc.1",
    "@angular/router-deprecated":  "2.0.0-rc.1",
    "@angular/upgrade":  "2.0.0-rc.1",

    "systemjs": "0.19.27",
    "es6-shim": "^0.35.0",
    "reflect-metadata": "^0.1.3",
    "rxjs": "5.0.0-beta.6",
    "zone.js": "^0.6.12",

    "angular2-in-memory-web-api": "0.0.7",
    "bootstrap": "^3.3.6"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "concurrently": "^2.0.0",
    "lite-server": "^2.2.0",
    "typescript": "^1.8.10",
    "typings":"^0.8.1"
  }
}
```

My application worked fine after some import rewrite, but now, I don't have autocompletion anymore for the angular framework on my IDE.

For example, IntelliJ doesn't recognize the *ngIf directive in my templates

Here is my tsconfig.json :

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es5",
    "module": "commonjs",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "removeComments": false,
    "noImplicitAny": false
  },
  "exclude": [
    "node_modules",
    "typings/main",
    "typings/main.d.ts"
  ]
}
```

Do I need to configure something else to make it work again?

Thanks for your answers

Comment: Are you really using intellij-14, or is that a mistaken tag? If you are, I wouldn't expect much in the way of ng2 support - that's still coming together in the bleeding-edge (2016.x) versions

Comment: I'd recommend WebStorm for Angular2 development. It's from the same developers as IntelliJ, but WebStorm supports Angular2 + Typescript.

Comment: @Patrick2607 - IntelliJ is a superset of all Jetbrains IDEs. i.e. the full functionality of WebStorm, Pycharm et. al. can be incorporated into IntelliJ via plugins.

Comment: angular is updated lets wait for webstrom update its not even allowing *ngFor ,(submit), etc

Comment: Found the answer right here https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-21500

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to a [comment in the IntelliJ bug tracker](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-21500#comment=27-1443218), the fixed the issue in 2016.1.2 EAP.  I updated to 2016.1.3 EAP, or more specifically:

```
IntelliJ IDEA (Minerva) IU-145.1503.17
Build #IU-145.1503, built on May 20, 2016
```

and it resolved the issue for me.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend using WebStorm, Jetbrains' web-centered IDE. It has out-of-the-box support for Angular 2 and even has a fancy interface for running npm scripts.

https://www.jetbrains.com/webstorm

Answer (score -1):

You can try [ang2-autocomplete](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ang2-autocomplete)
Here is usage sample : plnkr.co/edit/5zRD0fcOZHXEMOk4kupY?p=preview

Comment: I think the author wants a autocompletion with an IDE not in the frontend web code/browser :-/